# Is data safety guaranteed while using `ThreadPoolExecutor` from python's `future` module?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a conceptual answer on this question.

I'm wondering whether using `ThreadPool` in python to perform concurrent tasks, guarantees that data is not corrupted; I mean multiple threads don't access the **critical data** at the same time.

If so, how does this `ThreadPoolExecutor` internally works to ensure that **critical data** is accessed by only one thread at a time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thread pools do not guarantee that shared data is not corrupted. Threads can swap at any byte code execution boundary and corruption is always a risk. Shared data should be protected by synchronization resources such as locks, condition variables and events. See the [threading module docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html)

`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` is a thread pool specialized to the `concurrent.futures` async task model. But all of the risks of traditional threading are still there.

If you are using the python async model, things that fiddle with shared data should be dispatched on the main thread. The thread pool should be used for autonomous events, especially those that wait on blocking I/O.

Comment: I want to specifically know the behaviour of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, from `futures` module, is there any inherent mechanism in `ThreadPoolExecutor` to ensure that data is not corrupted?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma No. All the threadpool does is safely dispatch the work items you've given it across the workers. If the jobs / work items themselves are not threadsafe the pool will not magically make them so.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - I added a note about ThreadPoolExecutor specfically. Its workers have the same access to the process data... and the same risks.

Comment: @tdelaney What about GIL in CPYTHON??

Comment: A single GIL is used for all python threads in a single process. You are guaranteed that any one python byte code is atomic (with respect to other python threads - but not generally to non-python code such as C libraries) but the GIL lock is reacquired every .005 seconds (see `sys.getswitchinterval()` for your system) potentially causing a thread switch and loss of atomicity.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - suppose you did everything in the python `async` framework without using any additional threads. In that case you wouldn't have to worry about critical data changing in any code extent that doesn't make external calls. That's the beauty of `async` and why some people believe its an inherently safer way to do things. I've worked on several highly successful commercial products that work similarly and even though they are harder to code, they are saver when sent out into the wild.

Answer (score 4):

> If so, how does this ThreadPoolExecutor internally works to ensure that critical data is accessed by only one thread at a time?

It doesn't, that's your job.

The high-level methods like `map` will use a safe work queue and not share work items between threads, but if you've got other resources which can be shared then the pool does not know or care, it's your problem as the developer.